# Combining or grouping rows based on identical columns

Tags: .net, linq, grouping

I'm trying go over an array of DataRows in order to combine identical rows based on three columns, but even after doing a bit of research on this, I'm still not sure where to begin.

For example, supposing the DataRow columns I want to group by are called `UserID`, `ProjID` and `WorkID`, plus a bunch of other columns which I can ignore. There's also another important column called `Hours`, which I'm going to add up for each group. Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

**Initial:**

```
UserID |  ProjID | WorkID | Hours
---------------------------------
1      |   55    |   1    |  3
---------------------------------
1      |   55    |   5    |  2
1      |   55    |   5    |  5
1      |   55    |   5    |  6
---------------------------------
1      |   77    |   5    |  2
---------------------------------
2      |   77    |   2    |  7
2      |   77    |   2    |  2
```

**Combined:**

```
UserID |  ProjID | WorkID | Hours
---------------------------------
1      |   55    |   1    |  3
---------------------------------
1      |   55    |   5    |  13 (sum of 6 + 5 + 2)
---------------------------------
1      |   77    |   5    |  2
---------------------------------
2      |   77    |   2    |  9 (sum of 7 + 2)
```

Any ideas on how I should begin? Also, I'm open to any and all approaches, not just LINQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select columns and sum of columns using group by keyword from data table in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016016/how-to-select-columns-and-sum-of-columns-using-group-by-keyword-from-data-table)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `linq-to-entities`, `linq-to-sql`, `linq-to-objects`?

Regardless, your solution should look something like this:

```
var query = from x in list
            group x by new { x.UserID, x.ProjID , x.WorkID } into g
            select new
            {
              g.Key.UserID,
              g.Key.ProjID,
              g.Key.WorkID,
              Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Hours),
            };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects. I'm not using the Entity Framework, if that's what you're asking. Unfortunately I'm stuck with DataTables for this one.